# Triggers Google table. Current date for trigger specific date?

Tags: google-apps-script

What a [current date for trigger specific date?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw2Ux.jpg) I write 11.04.2020, 12:00 like this, but it is not correct.

Comment: Sorry but I can only read English.

Comment: 2020-04-10 12:00  on my dialog the pattern is on the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2020-04-10 12:00

[image]

The format string is at the bottom  of the page on the left.

Comment: Thank you very much!